# Help creating a product download PDF - requiring customer details

Tags: products, pdf, data, download

We'd like to have a PDF download as a product on our website, one that is actually a free project - but we want customers to have to enter their data to receive it. Is there a way I can handle this in a totally automated way within magento or do I need to set up the product as something they buy and then manually email them the pdf afterwards? Any help gratefully received,
thank you.

Comment: this kind of functionality you have to develop custom

Comment: *I like these sort of blanket statements.* Standard Magento has 'downloadable products'. A 'download' can be anything you can download over the internet, including a file in the PDF portable document format. However, customers have to create an account rather than just hand over their email address. If you want an easy way to do it on just email, use the newsletter signup and change the template for the 'success' email to send them the link to the PDF in the newsletter.

Comment: I thought that might be the way it had to work -- was just trying to remove a layer of manual labour!